# Migrate from SQL Server Evaluation to SQL Server Express

Tags: sql-server

I was using a trial edition of SQL Server, but the trial period ran out. I have downloaded SQL Server Express edition and want to migrate to it.

How do I do this, since I can no longer access SQL Server?

Comment: You mean you want to migrate the databases? If so, you could try to stop the service of the old one and than attach the databases files to new one, but it may run in a incompatibility version problem.

Comment: 1) What are the year-editions for each 2) Is this a production database you are using for an app/business or is this for personal use?

Comment: 2017. This is for personal use.

Answer (score 1):

If for development and test purposes you can perform an [in-place upgrade](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/install-windows/supported-version-and-edition-upgrades-2017?view=sql-server-2017) from SQL Server 2017 Evaluation Edition to SQL Server 2017 Developer Edition, which is a [free download](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sql-server/sql-server-downloads).

If you need to run a production workload on your desktop that needs a local SQL Server instance, then you can install a new instance of SQL Server Express Edition, and [attach](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/database-detach-and-attach-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017) the databases to that instance.

To migrate the databases copy them from the old instance data folder to the new instance data folder, and then attach them with SSMS or TSQL commands. See [Attach a Database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/attach-a-database?view=sql-server-2017).

eg copy the .mdf and .ldf files from:

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL14.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA
```

to

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL14.NEWINSTANCE\MSSQL\DATA
```

You may get warnings from Windows Explorer that you need to change the file security to access this folder, and you may need to change the file ACLs to enable the new instance to attach the databases.

Comment: Ok I did that. Thanks. How do I migrate my existing DB?